# jquery is loading page files when supposed to be not

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a jquery script that i call every time user wanted to save an item.
scripts works fine with other page except for the pages where i'm getting the URI->SEGMENT of the URL.

```
http://dev.sitename.ng/product/sc/UUtSNEJPMWxGWXl5ejlZaThrRGNadz09
```

Problem: every time user save an item it loads the other files running to that page (i check this thru the inspect>network), unlike in other pages it only read/run the script (works good). see my script below

[network result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUc3X.png)

Solution i'm looking for is it will stop jquery to load files of the page and run only the script

or

save url into a variable and extract the url segments.

PS. on load there is no problem and it saves the item after click but returning error on the page - see error at the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to:

1. use return false - for jquery to stop but still loading.
2. change the way of calling or getting URL but doesn't work.
3. save current url to a variable and tried to extract the segments

```
http://dev.sitename.ng/product/sc/UUtSNEJPMWxGWXl5ejlZaThrRGNadz09
```

4. tried search for the same problem but google don't give an answer that incline with my question/problem.
5. and other stuff

SCRIPT

```
function save_remove(id)
{
    var sid = 'saved'+id;
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : '/saved/save_remove/' + (id),
        success : function(data) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
                if(data.message == 'saved')
                {
                    $('#'+sid).removeClass('btn-outline-danger').addClass('btn-outline-secondary');
                    $('#'+sid).removeClass('saved_add').addClass('saved_remove');
                    $('#'+sid).attr('title', 'Remove saved item');
                    $('#'+sid).attr('data-original-title', 'Remove saved item');
                }else{
                    $('#'+sid).removeClass('btn-outline-secondary').addClass('btn-outline-danger');
                    $('#'+sid).removeClass('saved_remove').addClass('saved_add');
                    $('#'+sid).attr('title', 'Save item');
                    $('#'+sid).attr('data-original-title', 'Save item');
                }

                saved_counter();
            }else{
                $('#modal_sm').modal('hide');
                $('#sm_content').html(data.message);
                $('#modal_sm').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
}


function saved_counter(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'saved/count_saved/',
        success : function(response) {
            $("#saved_qty").html(response);
            $("#sb_saved_qty").html(response);

        }
    });
}
```

my controller

```
function sc(){
        $EncryptSubCatID = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $SubCatID = Modules::run('secure/encrypt_decrypt','decrypt',$EncryptSubCatID,'847EJDALQIS2PE3UDKA7128409EJA');

        $data['prodtype'] = $this->product->get_typebysc($SubCatID);

        $query1 = "my query here";
        $data['SubCatItem'] = $this->db->query($query1,array($SubCatID))->result();

        $query = "sp here ?";
        $data['detail'] = $this->db->query($query,array($SubCatID))->row();

        $this->load->view('subcat_display', $data);

    }
```

Severity: Notice

Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/subcat_display.php

Line Number: 23

```
<li class="active"><?php echo $detail->SubCatName; ?></li>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$this->db->query($query,array($SubCatID))->row()` actually returns an object? Do a `var_dump($data['detail']);` and check what the value is. There's also no validation of any data anywhere. If someone access that URL directly (but changes the last URL segment), your code would still try to decode and then use the result for db-queries.

Comment: Yes!
everything works fine on load but not after clicking save button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the JQUERY where in i forgot to put / before the controller

```
function saved_counter(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'saved/count_saved/',
        success : function(response) {
            $("#saved_qty").html(response);
            $("#sb_saved_qty").html(response);

        }
    });
}
```

solution

```
url : '/saved/count_saved/',
```

Thanks for those who tried to help.

Comment: How would that cause the error _"Trying to get property of non-object"_ and what does that request have to do with the posted PHP code?

Comment: from jquery, i'm calling a php function and from that function i am displaying an output from PHP code. i tried alot of stuff but yeah with that slash solves everything. Aha, I wonder as well if your comment makes sense in solving the problem.